# Domain access + Nodestream

Tags: domain-access

I am responsible of making a county based community newspaper so that means I will have something like *.domain.com eg. a.domain.com, b.domain.com, etc.

Now I don't want content from a.domain.com to be visible through b.domain.com enters domain access which made my life so blissful and achieved this relatively easily. Now I am trying to achieve the same using Nodestream. I have been at it for months and would really need some help on this. Any ideas?

Comment: I dont understand how NodeStream changes anything with regard to Domain Access? I'm not aware of anything NS does that would interfere with DA.

Comment: Hey, am also baffled by this. I have tried everything lest getting into DA code. At first I tried th NS distribution nothing worked, then I uninstalled it and started with drupal and DA worked perfectly and then finally installed NS as an addon....back to square one.

Comment: Hey Letharion, I have come to figure it has something to do with the webnewspaper module. Let me try an update and get back.